# Generating a random uint64_t

Tags: c++, random, c++14

Given a [random number engine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberEngine) `e` of arbitrary type `E`, how can I generate a random `uint64_t` over the full range?

Something like this, where the `needs_random()` function wants a random `uint64_t` and the `blah()` function is written in the modern `<random>` style which accepts a random engine of any type `E`.

```cpp
void needs_random(uint64_t r);

template <typename E>
void blah(E& engine) {
  // ...
  needs_random(???);
}
```

Specifically, I am trying to seed an xorshift random number generator from an arbitrary engine `e`, and the xorshift generator needs two `uint64_t` values as seeds.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195157/discussion-on-question-by-beeonrope-generating-a-random-uint64-t).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be portable, just use `unsigned long long` with `std::uniform_int_distribution` (or any other distribution you need):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

void needs_random(uint64_t r) {
    std::cout << r << "\n";
}

template <typename E>
void blah(E& engine) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long> dis(
        std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::min(),
        std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max()
    );
    needs_random(dis(engine));
}

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    blah(gen);
    blah(gen);
}
```

The type `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64-bits wide. The implicit integer conversion from `unsigned long long` to `uint64_t` should extract only the least significant 64 bits of the number.

This code will only be sub-optimal on platforms where like `sizeof(unsigned long long) * CHAR_BIT > 64`, cause the higher bits will just be unused. But the code will still be portable to such platforms and will still work.

Comment: Yes, , but I don't like "magic constants" in code (and 0 is NULL), so I try always to tell other programmers when they read the code from where the constant is.

Comment: well, nothing will protect you from a user passing a unsuitable generator and getting bad random numbers. you even just did pass the 32bit version of the mersenne twister,

Comment: Yes, but I assumed "maybe there is some magic inside the uniform_int_distribution implementation that could speed things up if we specify maximum value to the distribution". I don't know if it's true, but could be possible that the implementation is smart enough to do such optimizations (ex. the generator gives only 8 bits per generation. So the implementation can optimize not to generate more then 64-bits from the generator, saving entropy, I think so).

Comment: @skeller - what do mean by "unsuitable generator"? AFAICT there is no such thing as an unsuitable generator that conforms to the RNE concept. Passing the 32-bit generator is fine: the job of `uniform_int_distribution` is to handle such cases and it will call the generator multiple times to get enough bits to fill out the requested value.

Comment: @KamilCuk - oh, I see now you used `uint64_t` in the limits and `unsigned long long` in the type, so yeah it makes total sense. You are correct, the `uniform_int_distribution` will only use about as many bits as is needed to produce the requested range, so in the case that `ull` is say 128 bits, and the generator 64 bits or less, this helps. Deleting my old comments (and this one, shortly...).

Comment: @BeeOnRope you're correct. my comment is partly wrong. The user may only screw it up if the passed engine does not comply with the RandomNumberEngine requirements from the standart.

Comment: Thanks, it works - but man is it slow: because `uniform_int_distribution` is totally generic, works for any range it does a bunch of divisions, etc. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> dis;

    std::cout << dis(gen) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

you can repeadetly use  `dis(gen)` to generate more random numbers.

Comment: This is bogus proposal - one should use std::mt19937_64 for generating 64bits

Comment: This doesn't address the issue stated in the comments above, though.

Comment: Constraints ought to be given in the question to avoid wasting time

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I think all the constraints are given in the question? Even the original version, although now I added a code sample to make it clearer. I take _as an argument_ a RandomNumberEngine (see named requirement) of arbitrary type `E`, and from there need to generate some a random 64-bit value.

Comment: well, why give "half" of the responsibility to the caller? Give him a interface with a "GetRandomUint64" function to implement and provide a "default" implementation as suggested, if the caller does not want to provide his own random number generator.

Comment: @skeller - the caller has no responsibility except to pass in a random number engine. I think this is the standard way of writing random-using functions in C++. Random producing functions that don't take an engine don't make much sense: where are you going to get the seed value? Unless you are talking about functions that use a global or thread-local seed so produce unpredictable results (I'm not and IMO there is little use for these in good code).

Comment: @BeeOnRope valid argument. I usually would give the (not perfect global seed) default implementation and the user the option to provide something better. So the next junior dev using my class will be less likely to use it wrong

Comment: Well I would argue not thinking about where the seed value comes from is "using it wrong", since you'll get non-reproducible results, for example. There are two separate concerns here: the RNG implementation (i.e., type of rng it is, the "code") and the state (i.e., the current state of the rng). It's really the latter I'm concerned about: I think defaulting the implementation would be fine, but there is no sane, IMO, way to default the seed. Since C++ mixes the implementation and the seed together in the a single thing called "engine", I end up not defaulting the engine either.

Comment: @BeeOnRope as said, very valid argument, really depends on the scenario used and the target audience.